# Cannot resolve constructor FirefoxDriver(org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Can someone help me with this piece of code. Currently it will complain on line #4
: webDriver = new FirefoxDriver(ff_ep_profiles)
saying it cannot resolve constructor. I need to load my extensions hence I am creating a profile

```
FirefoxProfile ff_ep_profile = new FirefoxProfile(new File("C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\81uy033g.FirefoxEP"));
    FirefoxOptions option=new FirefoxOptions();
    option.setProfile(ff_ep_profile);
    webDriver = new FirefoxDriver(ff_ep_profile);
```

Comment: Where is WebDriver driver ? perhaps you are trying to create a variable webDriver, instead of WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver(ff_ep_profile);

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While working with *Selenium v3.11.x*, *GeckoDriver v0.20.0* and *Firefox Quantum v59.0.2* there are different option to invoke a new/existing **Firefox Profile**

If you are looking to use a *new* **Firefox Profile** on every run of your *Test Execution* you can use the following code block :

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\path\\to\\geckodriver.exe");
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.setProfile(new FirefoxProfile());
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
driver.get("https://www.google.com");
```

If you are looking to use an *existing* **Firefox Profile** on every run of your *Test Execution* first you have to create a **Firefox Profile** manually following the instructions at [**Creating a new Firefox profile on Windows**](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Creating_a_new_Firefox_profile_on_Windows).

Now you have 2 ways to invoke the **Firefox Profile** you have created as follows :

- You can use the **FirefoxOptions** class to invoke the existing *Firefox Profile* and you can use the following code block :

  ```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\path\\to\\geckodriver.exe");
  ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
  FirefoxProfile testprofile = profile.getProfile("debanjan");
  FirefoxOptions opt = new FirefoxOptions();
  opt.setProfile(testprofile);
  WebDriver driver =  new FirefoxDriver(opt);
  driver.get("https://www.google.com");
  ```
- You can also use the **DesiredCapabilities** class to set the existing *Firefox Profile* and later merge within an instance of **FirefoxOptions** and you can use the following code block :

  ```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\path\\to\\geckodriver.exe");
  ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
  FirefoxProfile testprofile = profile.getProfile("debanjan");
  DesiredCapabilities dc = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
  dc.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, testprofile);
  FirefoxOptions opt = new FirefoxOptions();
  opt.merge(dc);
  WebDriver driver =  new FirefoxDriver(opt);
  driver.get("https://www.google.com");
  ```

Comment: Any suggestions how I can load a profile when I am using remote webDriver...basically the purpose of the profile is so that I can load an extension.

Comment: As you are loading the _FirefoxProfile _ through _DesiredCapabilities_ class you can always pass that.