# "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed" when trying to launch Firefox

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, geckodriver

I am using Selenium 3.12,gecko driver version-21 and i have Firefox-61 installed on my system.

I am trying to launch Firefox using the code below:

```
System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv4Stack" , "true");
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\geckodriver.exe");
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.setCapability("marionette", true);
options.setLogLevel(FirefoxDriverLogLevel.TRACE);
options.setBinary("C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");
ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
FirefoxProfile fxProfile = profile.getProfile("xyzProfile");
fxProfile.setPreference(FirefoxProfile.PORT_PREFERENCE,7056);
driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```

However i am getting the below error and not able to even launch the browser-

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.net.SocketException:
>   Software caused connection abort: recv failed Build info: version:
>   '3.12.0', revision: '7c6e0b3', time: '2018-05-08T14:04:26.12Z' System
>   info: host: 'INDA201695', ip: '10.164.59.166', os.name: 'Windows 7',
>   os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_131' Driver
>   info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver

Please help as to what is causing this error and how can i fix the same?

Comment: How are you `trying to launch Firefox`? Using new/existing `FirefoxProfile`? What is your exact usecase?

Comment: I am trying to launch firefox using existing profile.I even tried without mentioning the profile statements but it did not work.

Comment: The exact use case is just to launch firefox and browse the url of my application.

Comment: Check this discussion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49683355/cannot-resolve-constructor-firefoxdriverorg-openqa-selenium-firefox-firefoxprof

Comment: I tried with the code mentioned on this link.
But still i am unable to launch firefox and getting the error message while debugging:

org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
Build info: version: '3.12.0', revision: '7c6e0b3', time: '2018-05-08T14:04:26.12Z'
System info: host: 'INDA201695', ip: '10.164.59.166', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed 
 Build info: version: '3.12.0', revision: '7c6e0b3', time: '2018-05-08T14:04:26.12Z' 
 System info: host: 'INDA201695', ip: '10.164.59.166', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_131' 
 Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
```

...implies that the *GeckoDriver* was unable to initiate/spawn a new *WebBrowsing* Session i.e. *Firefox Browser* session.

Your main issue is the incompatibility between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- Your *JDK version* is **1.8.0_131** which is pretty **ancient**.

So there is a clear mismatch between the *JDK v8u131* and other binaries.

### Solution

- Upgrade *JDK* to  recent levels [**JDK 8u181**](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
- Upgrade *Selenium* to  current levels [**Version 3.14.0**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- Upgrade *GeckoDriver* to [**GeckoDriver v0.20.1**](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) level.
- Ensure GeckoDriver is present in the specified location.
- Ensure GeckoDriver is having executable permission for non-root users.
- Upgrade *Firefox* version to ***Firefox v61.0.2*** levels.
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Execute your `Test` as a non-root user.