# Getting java.lang.NullPointerException in profile.setPreference("browser.popups.showPopupBlocker", false);

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver, firefox-profile

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\geckodriver.exe");

ProfilesIni profile2 = new ProfilesIni();

FirefoxProfile profile3 = profile2.getProfile("AutoProfile");
profile3.setPreference("browser.popups.showPopupBlocker", false);          
profile3.setPreference("browser.download.dir", "D:\\WebDriverDownloads");
profile3.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
profile3.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;"); 
profile3.setPreference( "browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false );
profile3.setPreference( "pdfjs.disabled", true );  

FirefoxOptions firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
firefoxOptions.setProfile(profile3);

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxOptions);
```

Comment: what is the reason you are using that preference? showPopupBlocker preference is used to show/hide an icon in the status bar when a pop-up is blocked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most probhable reason you are seeing a **`java.lang.NullPointerException`** is because the *Firefox Profile* which you are trying to use i.e. **AutoProfile** doesn't exist (yet to be created) on your local system.

### Solution

- Before you start using the *Firefox Profile* **AutoProfile** ensure that this *Firefox Profile* exists in your local system. You can create a **Firefox Profile** manually following the instructions at [**Creating a new Firefox profile on Windows**](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Creating_a_new_Firefox_profile_on_Windows).
- To configure auto downloads `setPreference("browser.popups.showPopupBlocker", false)` is not required so you can remove it.
- Execute your `@Test`.
- Here you can find a detailed discussion on [how to use a new/existing *Firefox Profile* for your tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49683355/cannot-resolve-constructor-firefoxdriverorg-openqa-selenium-firefox-firefoxprof)

Comment: @RajatPrajapati My answer was to address yous issue regarding `java.lang.NullPointerException`. If your requirement have changed, feel free to raise a new question. Stackoveflow volunteers will be happy to help you out.

Comment: ok.....I got rid of NullPointerException. However still auto download not working