# How to use both the Firefox Profile and Firefox options with Selenium in Java

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, headless, selenium-firefoxdriver

I'm writing a test that I'd like to headless, which will also download a file within java using Selenium. from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63143518/org-openqa-selenium-timeoutexception-connection-refused-error-while-running-hea) I learn that you can set a driver to be headless by throwing this code before you initialize the driver:

```
options.setHeadless(true); //sets driver to work headless 
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```

and that I can use this [method](https://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/how-to-download-a-file-with-webdriver#:%7E:text=To%20handle%20Downloads%20with%20selenium,%20we%20need%20to,check%20if%20the%20file%20is%20downloaded%20or%20not.) to write a Firefox Profile which will dictate a download directory and allow me to download a file with firefox w/o any pop up windows (I've modified the method to allow the method to permit the download location as an argument). After creating the method, I call it within main like this:

```
downloadPath = "C:\Scripts"
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(FirefoxDriverProfile(downloadPath));
```

and then say I want to use the following code with either of the two methods above:

```
driver.get(https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases);
driver.findElement(By.linkText("geckodriver-v0.27.0-win64.zip")).click();
```

I'll either not have a headless version of firefox running, or I get a pop up save prompt when I go to download the zip file.

How can I combine these two funcitons, the profile and the options?

edit: fixed the `setHeadless(false)` to be `setHedless(true)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use a new [Firefox Profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54661217/unknown-error-messageconnection-refused-stacktrace-while-trying-to-use/54664172#54664172) through `FirefoxOptions`  you can use the following code block:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\path\\to\\geckodriver.exe");
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.setProfile(new FirefoxProfile());
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
driver.get("https://www.google.com");
```

To use an existing [Firefox Profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52464598/how-can-i-set-a-default-profile-for-the-firefox-driver-in-selenium-webdriver-3/52474787#52474787) through `FirefoxOptions`  you can use the following code block:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\path\\to\\geckodriver.exe");
ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
FirefoxProfile testprofile = profile.getProfile("debanjan");
FirefoxOptions opt = new FirefoxOptions();
opt.setProfile(testprofile);
WebDriver driver =  new FirefoxDriver(opt);
driver.get("https://www.google.com");
```

To use an new [Firefox Profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53886741/selenium-tests-take-several-minutes-to-start-when-loading-a-profile/54072337#54072337) through `FirefoxOptions` along with [preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44074656/how-to-download-csv-file-through-firefox-profile-in-java/44084814#44084814) you can use the following code block:

```
String downloadFilepath = "C:\\path\\to\\MozillaFirefoxDownload";
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\path\\to\\geckodriver.exe");
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir",downloadFilepath);
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.setHeadless(true);
options.setProfile(profile);
WebDriver driver =  new FirefoxDriver(options);
driver.get("https://www.google.com");
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Cannot resolve constructor FirefoxDriver(org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49683355/cannot-resolve-constructor-firefoxdriverorg-openqa-selenium-firefox-firefoxprof/49686604#49686604)
- [unable to Pass FirefoxProfile parameter In webdriver to use preferences to download file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47568275/unable-to-pass-firefoxprofile-parameter-in-webdriver-to-use-preferences-to-downl/47569170#47569170)

Answer (score 1):

The function `options.setHeadless(false)` should have a `true` parameter not `false`

Comment: oh shoot, thanks for catching that. that being said, I still can only either call the driver with either the options or the profile, I dont know how to call them both.