# Intellij Idea cannot resolve constructor

Tags: java, selenium, intellij-idea

My problem is Firefox. I installed a different location. But I tried this solution isn't working for me.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxBinary;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;

import java.io.File;

 public class firefoxDriver
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    File pathBinary = new File("D:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");
    FirefoxBinary ffBinary = new FirefoxBinary(pathBinary);
    FirefoxProfile ffProfile = new FirefoxProfile();

    // Add .exe file
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:\\Docs\\Drivers\\geckodriver.exe");

    // Create Firefox object driver.
    WebDriver ffDriver = new FirefoxDriver(ffBinary, ffProfile);

    ffDriver.get("https://google.com");
    System.out.println(ffDriver.getTitle());

}
```

}

The error I get:
[image: Error]

Comment: Please look at this solution maybe it will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49683355/cannot-resolve-constructor-firefoxdriverorg-openqa-selenium-firefox-firefoxprof

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    // Add .exe file
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:\\Docs\\Drivers\\geckodriver.exe");
    File pathBinary = new File("D:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");

    FirefoxBinary ffBinary = new FirefoxBinary(pathBinary);
    DesiredCapabilities desired = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
    FirefoxOptions ffOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
    desired.setCapability(FirefoxOptions.FIREFOX_OPTIONS, ffOptions.setBinary(ffBinary));

    // Create Firefox object driver.
    WebDriver ffDriver = new FirefoxDriver(ffOptions);

    ffDriver.get("https://google.com");
    System.out.println(ffDriver.getTitle());
}
```

I solved my problem with this method. I don't know there is a much more simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

***N.B*** - In your particular example you do not need to create a profile. New profile is created automatically by default. You use profiles when you have some pre-configured profiles persisted before you run your driver.

You can do this:

```java
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.setBinary(new FirefoxBinary(new File("...")));
options.setProfile(new FirefoxProfile(new File("...")));
WebDriver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```

Another way to specify browser binary isto use system property:

```java
System.setProperty(
    FirefoxDriver
        .SystemProperty.BROWSER_BINARY, "PATH_TO_YOUR_BINARY");
```

If you have a named profile set up for your instance of firefox browser, then you should do the following (like in previous case **before** you create a driver):

```java
System.setProperty(
    FirefoxDriver
        .SystemProperty.BROWSER_PROFILE, "NAME_OF_PROFILE");
```

Comment: Thank you for answer but I think I cannot coded properly, it not worked.
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:\\exe");

        System.setProperty(FirefoxDriver.SystemProperty.BROWSER_BINARY, "D:\\.exe");

        FirefoxOptions ffOptions = new FirefoxOptions();

        ffOptions.setBinary(new FirefoxBinary(new File("D:\\")));

        ffOptions.setProfile(new FirefoxProfile(new File("D:\\")));

        WebDriver ffDriver = new FirefoxDriver(ffOptions);

        ffDriver.get("https://google.com");
        System.out.println(ffDriver.getTitle());

Comment: Given model profile directory is not a directory: D:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe

Comment: I'm not getting what it means. Why are you setting `new File("D\\")` as path to binary? It is not even a file. And of course not a Firefox binary.

Comment: I just shorted because of character limit.

Answer (score 0):

There is not constructor that is overloaded to have binary and profile together. You should use options.

**Code :**

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:\\Docs\\Drivers\\geckodriver.exe");
String pathBinary = "D:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe";
        
FirefoxOptions ffOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
FirefoxProfile ffProfile = new FirefoxProfile(pathBinary);
ffOptions.setProfile(ffProfile);
ffOptions.setBinary("C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox 52\\firefox.exe"); 
       
// Create Firefox object driver.
WebDriver ffDriver = new FirefoxDriver(ffOptions);

ffDriver.get("https://google.com");
System.out.println(ffDriver.getTitle());
```

Comment: Thank you for answer.
Given model profile directory is not a directory: D:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe gives me a new error.

Comment: Are you sure it's in D ? not in C ?

Comment: Yes, it's in D.
"Given model profile directory is not a directory: D:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" Error I got.

Comment: Please see above, updated code